# Find records with ids and keep the same order as in ids array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have ids array `ids = [5,2,1,6]`.

I'd like to find all records with these ids and keep the same order as in the `ids` array.

Regular `records = Product.find(ids)` does not keep this order(not sure, but probably it sorts by id).

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find - `records = Product.find(ids)` should keep order in recent Rails versions.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
ids = [5,2,1,6]
records = Product.find(ids).index_by(&:id).values_at(*ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using a CASE statement (Postgres).

```
def order_by_id(ids)
  order_by = ["case"]
    ids.each_with_index.map do |id, index|
    order_by << "WHEN id=#{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote id} THEN #{index}"
  end
  order_by << "end"
  order(order_by.join(" "))
end
```

That should get you most of the way there.

Comment: Using string interpolation to build SQL queries is an invitation for SQL injection attacks. Use Rails' built-in parameter binding.

Comment: @Jordan absolutely. This gets us part of the way there and isn't a complete solution. I'll update though.

Answer (score -1):

This will match each id to a product

`ids.map{ |id| Product.find(id) }`

Comment: This will do one query per element in the ids array, which is something you don't really want.

Comment: Imagine you have 10000 ids, you will hit the database 10000 times, while this can be done with a single query.